# Python def function return None in all cases

Tags: python

```
def leap(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 == 0:
            if year % 400 == 0:
                return True
    else:
        return False


print(leap(1992))
```

It always returns the `none` value but I want to print the `bool` in result

Comment: 1) write down code, don't put it in a image

Comment: 2) put every condition in and in the if (if it enters there and one of the two inner if is false, there is no else condition and it returns none)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would recommend reviewing [ask] for criteria on how best to post a question here in a way that will get you helpful feedback.  Specifically, you should always include a [mcve] as code (not an image) in your question, as well as a clear problem statement.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Try to think about the path the function does when it recieves the input you gave it (1992).

Comment: To give the OP an idea about what you can do with Python (and boolean logic). The whole function body could look like this: `return bool((not year % 4) and (year % 100) or (not year % 400))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code

```
def leap(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 == 0:
            if year % 400 == 0:
                return True
    else:
        return False


print(leap(1992))
```

Let's break it down for 1992.

1. year = 1992.

   1992 % 4 = 0. True. The code moves to next if statement.

   1992 % 100 = 92(False). so your codes halts at this point and exits from the function. Hence the `None` output for `1992` since you haven't added any logic to return false here.

A simple approach to avoid the `None` output would be.

```
def leap(year):
    if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(leap(1992))
```

Comment: But the logic is still wrong. Try it with the year `1992`.

Comment: For `1992`, you should get `False`. Could you please elaborate what you are trying to suggest?

Comment: @Amit 1992 is leap year, it shouldn't return False. check in your `if` logic.

Comment: I merely explained to him why his function was returning `None`. It is not my intention to do his task for him. The purpose was only to demonstrate why it was returning None.